# How do I select an element that matches a .text() == "" condition?

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is what I want to do:

```
<label class="myClass"></label> <!-- I want to hide this -->
<label class="myClass">Some text here</label> <!-- Don't hide -->

$('label.myClass').text() == "" ) {
        $('this').hide();
 }
```

Of course, `$(this)` points to window, not to the `label.myClass` that meets the condition. How do I rewrite so that I'm selecting all the labels that do nt have text inside it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var label = $('label.myClass').filter(function (index) {
    if ($(this).text() == "") {
        return $(this)
    }
})

console.log(label.attr('class'))
console.log(label.text())
console.log(label.length)
```

Use `.filter()`

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ro8vo5gc/1/)

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is like this:

```
$( "label.myClass" ).each(function( index ) {
 if ($(this).text() == "") {
   $(this).hide();
     }
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using `:empty` selector

```js
$("label.myClass:empty").hide()
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<label class="myClass"></label> <!-- I want to hide this -->
<label class="myClass">Some text here</label> <!-- Don't hide -->
```